# Instantiate a new Prefab

Tags: unity, c#

I’m developing a little 3D game to improve my Unity C# development.
However, I am faced with a recurring error that I cannot find the solution to :/
In fact, I always get the error **Nullreferenceexception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object** when I want to create a new Gameobject in my scene.

I wish I could spawn a bonus based on a percentage of chance when an enemy is killed.

So I created a Bonus mother class and a Bonushealth daughter class. So Bonushealth inherits the Bonus methods.

Here’s the mother class code (Bonus) :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Bonus : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected int lifeTime;

    public int LifeTime { get => lifeTime; set => lifeTime = value; }


    protected void RandomDropBonus(Transform posEnemy)
    {
        int chance = Random.Range(1, 100);

        switch (chance)
        {
            case int n when (n <= 100):
                Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("bonus"), new Vector3(posEnemy.position.x, posEnemy.position.y, posEnemy.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                break;
        }
    } 

    public void RandomBonus(Transform posEnemy)
    {
        int rdn = Random.Range(1, 1);
        Debug.Log(rdn);

        if(rdn == 1)
        {
            RandomDropBonus(posEnemy);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the daughter class code (BonusHealth) :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BonusHealth : Bonus
{
    public GameObject prefabHealth;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LifeTime = 10;
    }
}
```

I call the RandomBonus() method when an enemy is killed (in the Enemy class), Here's is the code :

```
private Bonus bonus;
bonus.RandomBonus(this.transform);
```

if I make Bonus bonus = new Bonus() 
I always get this error : **ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.**

In my prefab folder is contained my bonus prefab named bonus. I added the Bonushealth script on it.

I did a lot of research on the Internet but no way to find a solution :/

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is your "bonus" prefab inside a folder called "Resources"? And how does the enemy populate its `private Bonus bonus` variable?

Comment: Hello, in fact I had to create a resource folder containing my prefabs, now it works ! Thank for your answer ;)